# Footer is sticky, until I expand my accordion (html, css, vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion, sticky-footer

Basically my sticky footer is at the bottom of the page usually, works completely fine. However on the page with an accordion position:absolute, bottom:0, doesn't seem to be working once the accordion is expanded. Seen similar posts regarding this issue from a few years ago, but no solutions posted. Apologies in advance as I'm a newbie!

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
    .collapsible {
        background-color: #777;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 2%;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
      }
      
      .active, .collapsible:hover {
        background-color: #555;
      }
      
#footerContainer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class= "projectsContainer" id= "projectsContainer">

        <button type="button" class="collapsible">Front End</button>
        
        <div class="content">
          <div class = "Project">
          <h1 class="projectsTitle">Project</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content">
          <div class = "Project">
          <h1 class="projectsTitle">Project</h1>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      
        <button type="button" class="collapsible">Back End</button>
      
        <div class="content">
          <div class = "Project">
          <h1 class="projectsTitle">Project</h1>
        </div>
         <div class="content">
          <div class = "Project">
          <h1 class="projectsTitle">Project</h1>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
                <button type="button" class="collapsible">Full Stack</button>
      
        <div class="content">
          <div class = "Project">
          <h1 class="projectsTitle">Project</h1>
        </div>
         <div class="content">
          <div class = "Project">
          <h1 class="projectsTitle">Project</h1>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
        

                 
                 
                 <footer id = "footerContainer">
                    <button id = "githubBtn"><img class= "socials"</button> 
                    <button id = "linkedinBtn"><img class= "socials"</button> 
                    <button id = "instagramBtn"><img class= "socials"</button> 
                  
                  </footer>
```

Comment: But your footer isn't sticky? It's positioned absolutely, not using sticky. If you change it to     `position: sticky;` then it stays at the bottom regardless of the accordions being opened or closed. Also, you need to close your image tags before the closing button tags `></button>` See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: damn wish I could edit the post. Tried to edit the code so it wasn't as long and missed of the >! Okay cool so I think I misunderstood the concept of sticky then, thinking that it was a term, dough! However when I do position:sticky, it's still not sticking to the bottom and is instead moving around with the code!

Comment: You could use `fixed` instead which will force the footer to stay on the bottom no matter what. Sticky does what it implies, it sticks to the scroll versus fixed means that it's nailed down to wherever you tell it to be. The article I linked has a more elegant explanation than that but that's basically the gist of it.

Comment: With fixed it does stay at the bottom but scrolls with the accordion, very annoying. If I cold find a way for it to stop ding that with position:fixed we are cooking on gas!! Thank you, I appreciate that I'll check it out.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and let me know what you think, and we can workshop it from there but you're looking at the attributes and looking for mixed results. I can get you to where you want, I just need to know your desired end result :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest your footer inside the overall container if you want to keep the flow with the accordions and then use either `position: fixed` or `position: sticky` depending on your intention. Let me know how this works for you.

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {

  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}


.content {
  display: none;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

#footerContainer {
  position: aboslute;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="projectsContainer" id="projectsContainer">

  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Front End</button>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="Project">
      <h1 class="projectsTitle">Project</h1>
    </div>

      <div class="Project">
        <h1 class="projectsTitle">Project</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Back End</button>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="Project">
      <h1 class="projectsTitle">Project</h1>
    </div>
      <div class="Project">
        <h1 class="projectsTitle">Project</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Full Stack</button>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="Project">
      <h1 class="projectsTitle">Project</h1>
    </div>
      <div class="Project">
        <h1 class="projectsTitle">Project</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
                   
                 <footer id = "footerContainer">
                    <button id = "githubBtn"><img class= "socials"></button> 
                    <button id = "linkedinBtn"><img class= "socials"></button> 
                    <button id = "instagramBtn"><img class= "socials"></button> 
                  
                  </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: nice one legend!!! Looking a lot better. Next task for me is trying to figure out how to get my accordion to load closed!

Comment: See update, all you need to do is declare the content class to be `display: none` initially and then your JS display it when clicked. You'll also need to do some re-nesting for your projects because you don't need the content `div` multiple times for this.

Comment: awesome display:none did the trick. You are my favourite person today haha

Comment: No worries, if that answered your question please mark the check next to the answer and let me know if you need any more help :)